# Single.php not displaying post content on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, post

The theme I've installed isn't displaying post content - nothing other than the post title, categories etc. (http://www.laredohospitality.com/new-locations-opening/)
The summary doesn't seem to have a problem - http://www.laredohospitality.com/category/job-posting/

When switching over to TwentyTwelve, Thirteen, etc the posts display without a hitch so I know it's this theme buggering it up.

I've read up on Themeforest's Support but to no avail - lots of negative critique on this Theme's code to say the least but unless I can change my client's mind this is the theme they're happy with.

I tried a very basic single.php and that worked but I cannot implement this theme's sidebar and fancy extras without breaking that code.

Here is the single.php without any of my attempts at fixing it - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
    <div id="page-title-wrap">
        <?php 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            global $menuItem;
            if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( 12 ) ) {
                $menuItem=true;
            }
            else {
                $menuItem=false;
            }
        ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div id="page-title-content"><?php 
                    if ($menuItem) {
                        $pageId = 236;
                    }
                    else {
                        $pageId = 150;
                    }
                    $page=get_page($pageId);
                    echo $page->post_title; 
                ?>
                <img id="left-ornament" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/left_ornament.png" alt="Left ornament" />
                <img id="right-ornament" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/right_ornament.png" alt="Right ornament" />
            </div>
            <div id="page-title-descr"><?php echo "(".get_post_meta(150, "description", true).")"; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
    <div id="main-content">
        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="content-left">
            <div class="post-wrap">
                <?php if (!$menuItem) { ?>
                <div class="post-date">
                    <span class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span> 
                    <span class="month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></span> 
                    <span class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></span>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="post-header"><?php the_title() ?></div></a>
                <div class="post-info-wrap">POST BY: <span class="author-name"><?php the_author_posts_link() ?></span> in <a href=""><?php the_category(', '); ?></a> with <?php if ( get_comments_number() != 0 ) { ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() . '#comment-section' ?>"><?php comments_number(); ?></a><?php } else { comments_number('0 Comments'); }?> </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="post-header without-date"><?php the_title() ?></div></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="post-descr">
                    <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail('large');
                        } 
                        the_content(' '); 
                        endwhile; endif;

                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </div>
            <?php 
                comments_template(); 
                if ($menuItem) {
                    $categories = get_categories ( array( 'type' => 'post', 'child_of' => 12, 'order_by' => 'id') );
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        query_posts( array( 'cat' => $category->term_id, 'post_type' => 'post') );
                        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                        global $featuredDishes;
                        if ( $custom_fields['featured']==true ) {
                            $featuredDishes.="<img src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/star.png' alt='Star Icon' class='sidebar-popular-star' />";
                            $featuredDishes.="<a href='".get_permalink()."'>".the_title('','',false)."</a>";
                            $featuredDishes.="<div class='sidebar-desc'>".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ingredients", true)."</div>;";
                        }
                        endwhile; endif;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Prepare data for "Popular Posts" section
                    query_posts( array( 'cat' => "-12,-17", 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
                    $g=0;
                    global $popularPosts;
                    if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    if ( get_comments_number() > 0 ) {
                        $popularPosts[$g]['value'] = '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri(). '/images/star.png" alt="Star icon" class="sidebar-popular-star" />';
                        $popularPosts[$g]['value'].= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.the_title('','',false).'">'.the_title('','',false).'</a> ';
                        $popularPosts[$g]['value'].= '<div class="sidebar-desc">by ' .get_the_author(). ', '.get_the_time('d M y').'</div>';
                        $popularPosts[$g]['count'] = get_comments_number();
                    }
                    $g++;
                    endwhile;endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    // Sort post by comments count
                    function compare_count($a, $b){
                        return strnatcmp( $b['count'], $a['count'] );
                    }
                    usort($popularPosts, 'compare_count');
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
        <?php if (!$menuItem) { ?>
        <div id="content-right" class="addictional-contact">
            <?php get_sidebar('blog') ?>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="content-right" class="addictional-contact">
            <?php get_sidebar('menu') ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seemingly unrelated in the header (two ornament images) were affecting the post. Go figure.

Thanks for everyone's help! I deleted the code below and everything is in working order.

```
    <img id="left-ornament" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/left_ornament.png" alt="Left ornament" />
    <img id="right-ornament" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/right_ornament.png" alt="Right ornament" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm.. Try change `the_content(' ');` to `the_content();`

Maybe in `functions.php` file Special filters for content, which consequently spoil the output is added

Comment: Maybe in functions.php file Special filters for content, which consequently spoil the output is added

Comment: Observe the condition of sample content. if ($ menuItem) {

Comment: There is a filter or two regarding the_content in functions.php but when I tried commenting it out, there was no change.